# makefile for ARM: cannot specify -o with -c or -S and mult compilations

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm modifying this [makefile](http://www.hampleman.com/upload/Makefile2.txt) to use with another project and I get a gcc error saying I cannot specify -o with -c.

The line near the bottom that says:

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) ... -o $@ &<

has the -o

but CC_FLAGS = $(MCU_CC_FLAGS) -c ...

I don't see how this makefile worked in the first place.

Comment: Which GCC are you using? The two I've just tried accepted -c with -o just fine. Are you possibly [mixing source and object files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)?

Comment: This has to do with your make rules.  The command should be `gcc ... -c file.c -o file.o ...`, you are missing the file names.

Comment: Explain in detail and post the error, what modification you did